# Integrating appcompat with LibGDX's Gradle Projects in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat

I am attempting to merge a pre-existing Android project that uses appcompat with a game written using LibGDX. The problem is, I have no clue how to tell Gradle I need appcompat.

I've tried adding appcompat via the [usual method](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) (see the section labeled "Adding libraries with resources") and while this works for a regular project, it fails for the LibGDX's Gradle one. Where there is usually a check-mark verifying that a library project was added successfully, this just has a red x.

**Screenshots of Properties Pages:**

> [image]

**Example Errors due to this problem:**

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat'.

So my question is, **how do I build a LibGDX project with appcompat using Eclipse?**

Comment: Gradle-based Android projects, at least those that use the Android-Gradle plugin that Android Studio relies on, aren't supported in Eclipse. Do you have reason to believe that this should work?

Comment: @ScottBarta, this is the only way that I know of for doing it with LibGDX and it has built successfully prior to attempting to integrate appcompat. [Here's](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-(Eclipse,-Intellij-IDEA,-NetBeans)) a link for the LibGDX documentation, which speciffically instructs Eclipse users to download and install the [Eclipse Gradle Integration Plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html).

Comment: Looking at your build file linked to below under the answer, it's indeed using the Android plugin. I'd be shocked if Eclipse could figure out how to usefully make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding the dependency into the build.gradle file?

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
}
```

Comment: I tried that shortly after asking this question, it appeared to do no good. I tried the "Refresh Dependencies" option and even cleaned my project to no avail.

Comment: Did you try to add it underneath the project(":android") {    apply plugin: "android"  part?

Comment: Your `dependencies` block needs to be at the top level, not inside the `android` block.

Comment: @ScottBarta I didn't have it at the top level, now I do but there are still a ton of errors because it can't find appcompat. [Here's](http://i.imgur.com/0joCFuF.png) the top level gradle.build as I now have it setup (with those lines removed from the android one). Ok so I've highlighted several areas, it looks like I am pulling appcompat from two locations and why is one a .aar file?

Comment: According to http://www.androidsx.com/how-to-link-an-android-library-project-with-gradle-in-android-studio/ this link, you might need to link the project to it (as you would normally with Eclipse), albeit I don't have much experience with Gradle.

Comment: Yeah, appcompat is an AAR, which the Android Gradle plugin understands but which Eclipse itself doesn't know how to deal with. I think the LibGDX people are wrong when they tell people to use Gradle-based Android projects in Eclipse (at least those that use Google's Android Gradle plugin). It really doesn't work.

Comment: Worst case scenario, ask Nathan Sweet and the LibGDX crew. They're really helpful.